# Prevent parent element's content movement when a transitioning child is focused

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, overlay

Let's say I have a `container` which contains two divs:

- the first div is just a text container, no special style applied
- the second div is a `slider` which should slide in from the side of the `container` when necessary (e.g. upon a button click), overlays the text content, and it contains a button (or any other focusable element)

Upon opening the `slider`, right away as the transition animation begins, the `slider's` button get focused. This causes the button to be "forced" into the viewport. Because the `container's` overflow is hidden, it pushes the text content out of the way while animating.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis urna eget mi congue dignissim. Vestibulum at enim eu sapien posuere molestie at et nunc. Aenean tempor mi ut volutpat vehicula. Donec ut justo sit amet lectus convallis interdum quis id dui. Nullam lacinia ligula at tortor tristique accumsan. Phasellus nec arcu vel nisl porta vestibulum. Nulla aliquet arcu leo, at auctor orci sagittis quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</div>
    <div id="slider">
        Slider
        <button id="close_btn" type="button">X</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="open_btn" type="button">Open</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: grid;
    background: #ffccaa;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    animation: anim  10s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
    display: none;
}

#close_btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    0.01% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
let openBtn = document.getElementById('open_btn');
let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close_btn');
let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
openBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  slider.style.display = 'block';
  closeBtn.focus();
});
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  slider.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Here is a fiddle, please take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/732go0tx/

Commenting out the `focus()` on/of the `slider's` button solves the issue. I know I could just set the focus once the animation finishes but sadly this comes from a 3rd party (and a bit more complicated) code which may change any time, so I am trying to avoid overriding it.

Is there any way to prevent the focused element to be always "pushed" into the viewport? The slider should just slide in nicely, overlaying the text without pushing it out of its containing div.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the reason for the button having focus? And could you explain a bit more what you do and don't have control of. e.g. is that Javascript something you are able to alter?

Comment: @AHaworth The focus is set in the 3rd party code and is "trapped" in the slider (which serves as some kind of modal dialog). Originally the slider has position fixed and it is sitting on the body el. I would like to move the element from where it is (viewport/body) into a div with JS. It would work flawlessly but sadly that focus breaks it because I need to change position fixed into position absolute when I change its parent to be the said div.

Comment: So the only thing you can change is adding CSS, ie you can’t add JS or change the HTML structure, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: the initial suggestion was to Try:

```
  closeBtn.focus({
  preventScroll: true
});
```

This works for me (Chrome/Edge).

and I leave it here just in case it is of use to someone who has fewer restrictions on what they can alter.

Now I understand that neither the JS nor the HTML structure can be changed, here's a (slightly hacky to be honest) way of getting the required effect using only CSS.

As the system insists on making sure a focused element is within the viewport, we put the closing button just to the left of its parent element to begin with. It will seem to the system as though it is in the viewport (but the user wont see it as we set opacity 0) so the system doesn't do any scrolling off its own bat.

When the parent animation is nearly finished an animation set on the button comes into play and it fades into view (could come in suddenly, neither is a perfect solution but it does the job).

```js
let openBtn = document.getElementById('open_btn');
let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close_btn');
let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
openBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  slider.style.display = 'block';
  closeBtn.focus();
});
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  slider.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: grid;
  background: #ffccaa;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  animation: anim 10s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) forwards;
  display: none;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

@keyframes btn {
  0%,
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    right: 1%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }
}

#close_btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  animation: btn .2s linear forwards;
  animation-delaty: 10s;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  0.01% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis urna eget mi congue dignissim. Vestibulum at enim eu sapien posuere molestie at et nunc. Aenean tempor mi ut volutpat vehicula. Donec ut justo sit amet lectus convallis interdum quis
    id dui. Nullam lacinia ligula at tortor tristique accumsan. Phasellus nec arcu vel nisl porta vestibulum. Nulla aliquet arcu leo, at auctor orci sagittis quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    Slider
    <button id="close_btn" type="button">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="open_btn" type="button">Open</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly just seen it's not implemented in Safari (tested on IOS).

Comment: Sadly, that's part of the code I cannot control. Basically all JS is (in theory - cos of course I could override) out of reach.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you may not be able to modifie the javascript, so this example may not be valid. I just `disabled` the buttom so focus won't do anything and  turn it to `false` at the click event...

You may probable find a way to do the same with a new `script` not changing the actual one.

```js
let openBtn = document.getElementById('open_btn');
let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close_btn');
let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
openBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  slider.style.display = 'block';
  closeBtn.focus();  
  closeBtn.disabled = false;
});
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  slider.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: grid;
  background: #ffccaa;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  animation: anim  10s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  display: none;
}

#close_btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  0.01% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis urna eget mi congue dignissim. Vestibulum at enim eu sapien posuere molestie at et nunc. Aenean tempor mi ut volutpat vehicula. Donec ut justo sit amet lectus convallis interdum quis id dui. Nullam lacinia ligula at tortor tristique accumsan. Phasellus nec arcu vel nisl porta vestibulum. Nulla aliquet arcu leo, at auctor orci sagittis quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  </div>
    <div id="slider">
    Slider
    <button id="close_btn" type="button"  disabled>X</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="open_btn" type="button">Open</button>
</div>
```